# How to declare connection properties with ComboPooledDataSource or BasicDataSource

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence.xml

How to declare `useFetchSizeWithLongColumn=true` with Hibernate? either under `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource` or `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource` in a properties bean configuration file?

I already tried:

```
<bean id="oracle_prop" lazy-init="false"
      class="org.springframework.util.StringUtils"
      factory-method="collectionToDelimitedString">
    <constructor-arg index="0">
        <list>
            <value>oracle.jdbc.useFetchSizeWithLongColumn=true</value>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg value=";" index="1" type="java.lang.String"/>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
    <property name="initialSize" value="100"/>
    <property name="maxIdle" value="100"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="1000"/>
    <property name="connectionProperties" ref="oracle_prop"/>
</bean>
```

and

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="properties" ref="dataSourceProperties"></property>
    <property name="driverClass" value="${database.driver}"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${database.url}"/>
    <property name="user" value="${database.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
    <property name="initialPoolSize" value="100"/>
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="100"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="1000"/>
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="1800"/> 
    <property name="maxStatements" value="50"/> 
</bean>

<bean id="dataSourceProperties" class="java.util.Properties">
    <constructor-arg>
        <props>
            <prop key="oracle.jdbc.useFetchSizeWithLongColumn">true</prop>
        </props>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

and

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${database.driver}"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${database.url}"/>
    <property name="properties">
        <props>
            <prop key="user">${database.username}</prop>
            <prop key="password">${database.password}</prop>     
            <prop key="useFetchSizeWithLongColumn">true</prop>                  
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="initialPoolSize" value="100"/>
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="100"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="1000"/>
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="1800"/> 
    <property name="maxStatements" value="50"/> 
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround

Look for all the long data types and change each manually.

```
Select * from user_tab_columns c where c.DATA_TYPE = 'LONG';
```

Sad to say useFetchSizeWithLongColumn will not work everytime.
[So if you want to use this property, make sure that the LONG columns you are retrieving are not too big or you may run out of memory.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.html)

For JPA Hibernate, you could also add @Lob Annotation.

Answer (score 0):

```
<property name="connectionProperties" ref="oracle_prop"/>
```

This will not work as it will try to bind "object" or "property" type object to `connectionProperties` where as `setConnectionPropeties(String args)` expect a string argument. Try changing ref with value and it should inject property as String data type. Else we can also pass properties delimited with ";".